# Managing configuration files across multiple servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, configuration, configuration-files, apache-zookeeper

Running a Rails application on multiple servers (~20), I want to able to manage the configurartion files (mainly *.yml, but also SSL pem/certs files and other text based) from a single location such that any change to files, or a new file, is added to all servers.

I also want to have this content source controller via git.

Updated are not frequent and I want to keep the app untouched such that data is read from files as it is right now.

What are the available solution for that, is Zookeeper good fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used Zookeeper but I believe you should be able to do something like you need with a tool such as [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) or [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using Chef for various installation, however, I am not aware of Chef usage for configuration files management, do you have any specific pointers to such usage of Chef?

Comment: Sorry, I do not :) I've been meaning to try out both myself, just thought I'd throw that out there :) I'm assuming that you can keep a central repository of configuration files and have Chef/Puppet write them to a location on all the servers?

Comment: Did you figure this out with Chef?

Answer (score 0):

We're using ZooKeeper for live settings.
One idea is to use a registry.

Say you have a component called Arst.

You can have some config - lets say for redis under these folders each representing a different instance:

```
/dbs/redis/0 (host, port, db, password as children)
/dbs/redis/1 (host, port, db, password as children)
/dbs/redis/prod (host, port, db, password as children)
```

And if your component Arst needs to use instance 0, you can have a registry like this:

```
/arst/redis/0
```

If you want to add 1 just add the node and a child watch in the application will update things for you without a restart.
It's not very simple to do though and managing the settings can be a pain for teams like qa.

So I'll be working on a console to help with this as well. We'll be open sourcing some pieces.

Comment: Thanks, unless I miss something, this is zookeeper usage. How would you connect that to a rails app?

Comment: I'm stating you can put your config into zookeeper. I think I may have misunderstood the requirement a bit - indeed you're looking for a configuration management database (CMDB) if I understand correctly now.